# Samba server: Delay in changed LDAP group membership

Tags: ldap, samba

After switching from local user-groups to LDAP group memberships on our system, changing the memberships stopped being recognized immediately after performing the modification. Instead, we experience a delay of several minutes before the samba server applies the updated memberships.

Installed is a samba server `Version 4.5.16-Debian` and `OpenLDAP: slapd  (May 23 2018 04:25:19)`. The relevant section of the `smb.conf` configuration is:

```
passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://localhost
read only = yes
ldap suffix = dc=example,dc=com
ldap user suffix = ou=people
ldap admin dn = cn=admuser,ou=admgroup,dc=example,dc=com
ldap ssl = no
ldap passwd sync = yes

netbios name = EXAMPLE
netbios aliases = EXAMPLE2
obey pam restrictions = Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2009-August/149644.html) response of the samba mailing list, `nscd` caches the entries, which is typically installed alongside if LDAP is used for PAM/NSS as well:

```
# apt-cache show libnss-ldap |grep ^Recommends
Recommends: nscd, libpam-ldap
```

To trigger the modifications to be recognised immediately, the corresponding cache table can be invalidated via:

```
nscd --invalidate group
```